# Error: illegal start of expression with BlueJ

Tags: java

I am new to coding.  I am using BlueJ and the following code compiles fine but when I try to use the `add` method, I get an illegal start of expression.

As far as I can tell I do not have the method nested in the main or anything.

Looking for a little help.  Just wanted to test the add method and the other methods are not finished really.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Roster
{
    static ArrayList<Student> myRoster = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        printAll();
    }

    public static void add(int studentID, String firstName, String lastName, String eMail, int age, int grade1, int grade2, int grade3)
    {
        int[] grades = {grade1, grade2, grade3};
        Student newStudent = new Student(studentID, firstName, lastName, eMail, age, grades);
        myRoster.add(newStudent);

    }

    /**
     * An example of a method - replace this comment with your own
     *
     * @param  y  a sample parameter for a method
     * @return    the sum of x and y
     */
    public static void remove(int studentID)
    {

    }

    public static void printAll()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < myRoster.size(); i++)
        {
            myRoster.get(i).print();
        }
    }

    public static void printAverageGrade(int studentID)
    {
        for(Student eachStudent : myRoster)
        {
            double average = (eachStudent.getGrades()[0] + eachStudent.getGrades()[1] + eachStudent.getGrades()[2]) / 3.0;
            System.out.println("Student ID: " + eachStudent.getStudentID() + " Average Grade: " + average);
        }
    }

    public static void printInvalidEmails()
    {

    }
}
```

Here is the student class and the message I got was on the interface(new and don't know what it is called, see next sentence) which read "Error: illegal start of expression".  This happens when I right click the class Roster and go to the add method.  I then enter the inputs and get the error.  It does state at the top before the inputs Roster.add() which doesn't seem right to me.  Shouldn't it say myRoster.add?

If it helps, from the code pad(I don't even know if that is where I am suppose to add "students data") if I type the add method manually it gets an error of cannot find symbol - method add(.....)

```
public class Student
{
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private int studentID;
    private String eMail;
    private int age;
    private int[] grades;

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class Student
     */
    public Student( int studentID, String firstName, String lastName, String eMail, int age, int[] grades)
    {
        setStudentID(studentID);
        setFirstName(firstName);
        setLastName(lastName);
        setEMail(eMail);
        setAge(age);
        setGrades(grades);

    }

    /**
     * Gets the student's ID
     * @return  studentID
     */
     public int getStudentID()
    {
        return studentID;
    }
    //Mutator
    public void setStudentID(int studentID)
    {
        this.studentID = studentID;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the first name of the student
     * @return firstName
     */
    public String getFirstName()
    {
        return firstName;
    }
    //Mutator
    public void setFirstName(String firstName)
    {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the last name of the student
     * @return lastName
     */
    public String getLastName()
    {
        return lastName;
    }
    //Mutator
    public void setLastName(String lastName)
    {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the eMail of the student
     * @return eMail
     */
    public String getEMail()
    {
        return eMail;
    }
    //Mutator
    public void setEMail(String eMail)
    {
        this.eMail = eMail;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the student's age
     * @return age
     */
    public int getAge()
    {
        return age;
    }
    //Mutator
    public void setAge(int age)
    {
        this.age = age;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the student's grades
     * @return grades
     */
    public int[] getGrades()
    {
        return grades;
    }
    //Mutator
    public void setGrades(int[] grades)
    {
        this.grades = grades;
    }

    public void print()//prints specific student data
    {
        System.out.println("Student ID:\t" + getStudentID() + 
                            "\tFirst Name:\t" + getFirstName() + 
                            "\tLast Name:\t" + getLastName() + 
                            "\tEmail:\t" + getEMail() + 
                            "\tGrade1:\t" + getGrades()[0] + 
                            "\tGrade2:\t" + getGrades()[1] + 
                            "\tGrade3:\t" + getGrades()[2]);
    }
}
```

Comment: How is the Student class defined? What is the exact error you see?

Comment: Can you show us the code with the error?  Please don't make us guess!

Comment: Here is the student class.  The code I get is just "Error: illegal start of expression" on the interface

Comment: "On the interface"?  I don't see an interface.  Which file, and which line number?

Comment: So the code you've shown here doesn't actually have the error?  It happens when you try to add something?   Can you show code that actually _has_ the error?  It's  hard to tell from your description what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: It is hard to explain since I really don't know terminology of the BlueJ IDE.  When you open the package, your classes are shown by boxes.  If you right click on the class, you can select a method to run and it asks for inputs.  When you fill this out, it will create that object.  When I feel this out.  I get the error.  I tried a hard code at first which left the print command blank on the terminal.  How do you want me to describe it?

Comment: The code compiles fine but acts like the add method is not storing anything into the ArrayList or is just not coded right.

Comment: This is also all the code there is.  I am sorry that I am not making this more clear but I have only been at this for a couple of weeks.